# Heroku - Deploying React/Express app and getting 'Failed to load resource' in the console when requesting the chunk.js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am getting these errors in the console after my React app has been built and deployed on Heroku.

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://radiant-tor-66940.herokuapp.com/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.3174e036.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 1.b1e0c624.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.3174e036.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) manifest.json:1
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token. manifest.json:1
```

The `index.js` file is located in `/client/build/` on my Heroku server. This is the file my Express server sends. The server is sending this `index.html` file, but the file itself is not finding the resources it needs.

This is causing the issue of loading a blank app. Ffor some reason `index.html` is not finding the `chunk.js` files inside of `/client/build/static/js`. They are definitely in there and I can confirm with `heroku run bash` and inspecting the directories.

When I inspect the `index.html` document in the browser, I can see at the bottom where the script tags call the `chunk.js` files in `/static/js`:

[image]

This is what the root `package.json` for the app looks like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~9.10.1",
    "npm": "~5.6.0"
  }
```

This is what the `package.json` for the React app located in `/client` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/"
}
```

Here is what the file structure looks like on Heroku post-build:

- 1st image: `/client` directory
- 2nd image: `/client/build` directory
- 3rd image: `/client/build/static/js` directory

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue was actually in my `server.js` file, which I did not include on this post.

Originally it was `express.static(path_join(__dirname, '/client/build'))`

it needed to be: `express.static(path_join(__dirname, '../client/build'))`

This is the case because my `server.js` file is located in `/server` and it was trying to find `/client/build` inside of `/server` instead of the root app directory on Heroku.